# Что происходит при добавлении числа к символьному массиву

Tags: c++, строки, переменные

Есть команда : `strncmp(s.c_str(), sstr.c_str() + np - r - i, i)`

Где:

```
std::string s, sstr; // И как-то их заполнили
int np, r, i; // И как-то их заполнили
```

Мне непонятно, что происходит при добавлении числа к буквенному массиву:

```
sstr.c_str() + np
```

Comment: `c_str()` возвращает не "буквенный массив", а указатель на первый элемент этого массива, соответственно прибавление числа указателю задействует адресную арифметику и дает новый указатель, сдвинутый относительно исходного на указанное число.

Comment: sstr.c_str() это указатель на первый символ. Вы знаете что происходит при добавлении числа к указателью?... Вообше то  нет необходимости сравнивать С_массивы .  Удобнее использовать std::string ::compare

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо [**@user7860670**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272035/user7860670) и [**@ar-hovsepyan**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/277611/ar-hovsepyan) за помощь!

> c_str() возвращает не "буквенный массив", а указатель на первый
>   элемент этого массива, соответственно прибавление числа указателю
>   задействует адресную арифметику и дает новый указатель, сдвинутый
>   относительно исходного на указанное число

---

> Вообше-то нет необходимости сравнивать С_массивы . Удобнее
>   использовать std::string ::compare

Comment: *"Удобнее использовать std::string ::compare"* Или вообще `==`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,   она возвращает `int(1, 0, -1)`, тем самым можно узнать какая меньше при неравенстве, так что ` ==`  просто выдаст равны они или нет.  Так что неоднозначно _ неизвестна цель...